# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

What does this exception mean?

```
07-05 12:09:11.788: W/dalvikvm(445): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
07-05 12:09:11.808: E/AndroidRuntime(445): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 12:09:11.808: E/AndroidRuntime(445): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.a2zunitconverter.miniproject/com.a2zunitconverter.miniproject.weight}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
07-05 12:09:11.808: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
07-05 12:09:11.808: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-05 12:09:11.808: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-05 12:09:11.808: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-05 12:09:11.808: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-05 12:09:11.808: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-05 12:09:11.808: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-05 12:09:11.808: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 12:09:11.808: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-05 12:09:11.808: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-05 12:09:11.808: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-05 12:09:11.808: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-05 12:09:11.808: E/AndroidRuntime(445): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
07-05 12:09:11.808: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at com.a2zunitconverter.miniproject.weight.onCreate(weight.java:31)
07-05 12:09:11.808: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-05 12:09:11.808: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
07-05 12:09:11.808: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  ... 11 more
07-05 12:09:15.538: D/dalvikvm(454): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 49K, 53% free 2560K/5379K, external 2076K/2137K, paused 56ms
```

**Here is my xml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/weight4">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@string/weight"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/wquery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="@string/value" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/label2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/convertfrom"
                android:layout_width="126dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </Spinner>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="34dp"
                android:layout_height="61dp"
                android:background="#cccccc"
                android:src="@drawable/arrows" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/convertto"
                android:layout_width="137dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </Spinner>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/back1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="248dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="213dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/result"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/result"
                android:layout_width="269dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#66cc00" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/exit"
                android:layout_width="74dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/back" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Specifically weight.java, and point out line 31.

Comment: The question hasn't been updated with the code requested.  It is not answerable in its current form, and judging by the OP's inactivity, it is no longer relevant.  Voted to close.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you could have this error in Eclipse after modifying layout xml. Try to make "Clean Project" in Eclipse. That helps me.

Comment: It is unlikely that this will help.  It is much more likely that the real problem is that OP's code is buggy.  If he doesn't post it, we can't help him.

Comment: This is probably unrelated to the problem shown here but it helped me when I had a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

as you can see from this line: `07-05 12:09:11.808: E/AndroidRuntime(445): at com.a2zunitconverter.miniproject.weight.onCreate(weight.java:31)`

there is an error in your `onCreate` function in line number 31.

Answer (score 0):

The error `ClassCastException` means that you are trying to cast an object into a specific class that does not match its type.

It seems like you are trying to cast a LinearLayout Object into some other Object. If you post your java code we can be more specific.